# 32-bit x86 Assembly- Reversing Order of Array through Rotates/Shifts

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86

I googled this question for the past 2 hours and couldn't find exactly what's needed so I figured I'd ask for help.

So..

We have 2 arrays. Both have a length of 10. The first one stores your student/teacher/work ID number with a prefix of 0. For example: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

The goal of this program is to reverse the order by **using shifts and rotates** and store them in the second array.For example: 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0

I can't seem to figure out the algorithm; I've been staring at the screen for too long.

The other requirements are to sum the 2 values from each array and show the memory locations, but I think that won't cause me much trouble.

Precise Constraints:

Draft a program that adds two BCD numbers (10-digits each)
The first BCD number is stored in array1 and the reversed order will be stored in array2.

Use shifts/rotates using array1 to fill array2

Display contents of the memory locations in question 
Add both values by using BCD arithmetic
Store the sum in a variable named Result

Those were the requirements. No other information was given.

Thank you

Comment: Meaning, you can't use `mov` either? That's dumb. You can do it by rotating 2x8 times to replace a byte sized `mov` but somehow I doubt that's what the assignment wants you to do.

Comment: Well I shouldn't of put "only" there. I'd assume I can. I just meant that I can't use pointers and all of the easier stuff.

Comment: You need to access the memory somehow... `mov al, [arr1]; mov [arr2+9], al` and so on, which part is invalid?

Comment: I wish it was that easy. I just know I have to utilize shifts and rotates.

Comment: You can `rorw/rolw 8, (array)` to swap the first two elements, assuming the elements are bytes.

Comment: What x86 are we referring to exactly? 16, 32 or 64 bits? How big is each element of the array?

Comment: @EOF except he needs to copy into the other array. Yeah, we can make up some convoluted sequence involving rotates, but you still need to access the array, and you also said `mov` is allowed, so?

Comment: 32 bit, and whichever makes this easier.

Comment: This is unclear. Please edit the question with the **precise** constraints on what may be used, both instructions and addressing.

Comment: edited. Thats all that was given.

Comment: You'll need to ask your instructor what he or she means.  It's possible that the arrays are actually 5 bytes long with two BCD digits in each byte. These digits would need to be swapped in each byte in order to reverse the order of digits. The obvious implementation would the MOV instruction to to reverse the order bytes, and only use a ROL or ROR instruction to reverse the order of the digits within a byte. But this would appear to violate the constraints of your assignment so you'll need to ask.

Comment: I submitted an answer showing how you could reverse the array using only the `RCR` instruction but I deleted it because it corrupts the source array, and it appears that this not what the problem asks for. I suspect that there is a missing piece of information that would clarify the relevance of the shifts/rotates in this problem.